# Parallel Q-learning

Tags: neural-networks, references, reinforcement-learning, parallel-computing, pybrain

I'm looking for academic papers or other credible sources focusing on the topic of parralelized reinforcement learning, specifically Q-learning.
I'm mostly interested in methods of sharing Q-table between processes (or joining/syncing them together if each process have it's own).
I'd also appreciate a brief description of method used in linked/mentioned sources.

My question is how to parallelize Q-learning which uses neural network as Q-table approximation. I'm looking for credible sources.

I should mention that I use neural network (PyBrain) as approximation.

Answer (score 1):

- Start with  [IMPALA: Scalable Distributed Deep-RL with Importance Weighted Actor-Learner Architectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01561). There is plenty of references for older work. The idea is to do smart batching with off-policyness correction so that we can get a boost from using GPUs. In general, the idea is in sharing experiences, not the gradients between actors and learners.
- Look also at [A3C](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01783)/[A2C](https://blog.openai.com/baselines-acktr-a2c/) which does async/sync updates on the gradients the master node gets from the workers.
- [PPO](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06347) also does multi-thread learning when workers share the collected experience with the master node which updates the weights.
- Finally, since you asked for DQN, [GORILA](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.04296) paper which separates actors, learners and the main node which stores the weights (in tensorflow setting it's called `parameter server`). As far as I get it, this paper inspired IMPALA.